# Jquery a .Show() is not fully working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two functions. One that hides a Edit and Delete button, and shows a Save button, and another one that does the opposite (hides save, shows edit and delete).

Right now the first button works: Save appears and Edit/Delete disappear, but the second function does not work: It hides Save but only shows Delete...somehow Edit is not being shown.

button code within a `<td>`

```
<td class="col-lg-3 col-lg-offset-1">
    <span style="visibility:hidden" class="ID">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ID)</span>

    <span class="item-edit-button">
          <button type="button" onclick="someFunction(this)" class=" btn btn-warning col-lg-4"><span style="margin-right: 5px" class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span>Edit</button>
    </span>

    <span class="item-save-button">
          <button type="button" onclick="saveFunction(this)" class="btn btn-success col-lg-4"><span style="margin-right: 5px" class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>Save</button>
    </span>

    <span class="item-delete-button"> // no use right now - ignore
          <button type="button" onclick="deleteFunction(this)" class="btn btn-danger col-lg-4"><span style="margin-right: 5px" class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>Delete</button>
    </span>
</td>
```

the JQuery

```
<script>
    function someFunction(element) 
    {   
        $(element).hide();
        $(element).closest("td").find("span.item-save-button").show();
        $(element).closest("td").find("span.item-delete-button").hide();
    }

    function saveFunction(element) 
    {
        $(element).hide();  
        $(element).closest("td").find("span.item-edit-button").show();
        $(element).closest("td").find("span.item-delete-button").show();

    }
</script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/BrP2a/

Hopefully I am just making some silly mistake.

**ANSWER**
I was accidentally hiding the `button`, not the `span`, thus when I tried to show my edit button's span it did not work as the button itself was hidden originally to fix this I had to use.

```
function someFunction(element) {

        $(element).closest("span").hide();
        $(element).closest("td").find("span.item-save-button").show();
        $(element).closest("td").find("span.item-delete-button").hide();

    }

 function saveFunction(element) {

        $(element).closest("span").hide();
        $(element).closest("td").find("span.item-edit-button").show();
        $(element).closest("td").find("span.item-delete-button").show();  
    }
```

Comment: Just a suggestion but you should probably start considering binding to events utilizing jQuery instead of inline.  see jquery.on() http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: Why not use `click()` and get the JS out of your HTML?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have hide the actual button by `$(element).hide();` in `someFunction` and you are showing `item-edit-button` span so actual button is still hidden. Try this,

```
function saveFunction(element) 
{
    $(element).hide();  
    $(element).closest("td").find("span.item-edit-button button").show();
    $(element).closest("td").find("span.item-delete-button").show();
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much I completely missed that! I shall award you the answer since you got to it first

Answer (score 1):

You have to define the function before your HTML elements that mean if your elements are in body tag then you have to define the function in the head tag

then you can change the code little bit

```
function someFunction(element) 
{   
    $(element).hide();
    $(element).siblings("span.item-save-button").show();
    $(element).siblings("span.item-delete-button").hide();
}

function saveFunction(element) 
{
    $(element).hide();  
    $(element).siblings("span.item-edit-button").show();
    $(element).siblings("span.item-delete-button").show();

}
```

Here is the working fiddle for the code

http://jsfiddle.net/murli2308/YeZDe/

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is your use of the `.closest()` function, which finds the nearest **parent** of the given selector, starting with the selected element. [See documentation](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) for `closest()`.

You probably are intending to use the [`.prev()`](http://api.jquery.com/prev/) and [`.next()`](http://api.jquery.com/next/) functions.

Comment: `.closest()` is correct here.  The elements with onclick handlers, `<button>` in this case, don't have siblings.

Answer (score 0):

You are hiding the Element (the button) but them Showing the TD. So the result is TD is visible but button itself is still hidden.

Here is the working code:

```
function someFunction(element) 
{   
    $(element).closest("td").find("span.item-edit-button").hide();
    $(element).closest("td").find("span.item-save-button").show();
    $(element).closest("td").find("span.item-delete-button").hide();
}

function saveFunction(element) 
{
    $(element).closest("td").find("span.item-save-button").hide();  
    $(element).closest("td").find("span.item-edit-button").show();
    $(element).closest("td").find("span.item-delete-button").show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't answer your question directly, but I think it presents a simplification of your code that may help.

http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/BrP2a/4/

```
<button id="item-edit" ...>...Edit</button>
...

$('#item-edit').click(function () {
    $(this).hide();
    $('#item-save').show();
    $('#item-delete').hide();
});
$('#item-save').click(function () {
    $(this).hide();
    $('#item-edit, #item-delete').show();
});
```